# Reference a spreadsheet created from SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I currently have a separate speadsheet that contain formulas that reference a spreadsheet generated by SSRS however the SSRS spreadsheet is set to overwrite the data and it seems to delete the spreadsheet and creates a new one in its place which breaks the formulas.
Is there a way to not overwrite the spreadsheet so that it doesnt break the formulas or is there another alternative?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask about is not possible with SSRS. If you would like to have the ability to update the data in an Excel spreadsheet and maintain the formulas, PowerPivot is a solution.

Create an Excel workbook (or use the one you mention in your question), and add a Power Pivot data source and pivot table on one of the sheets in the workbook. Make sure the data pulled with PowerPivot includes all the data you need, and pivot table display all of that information.

On another sheet, add your formulas and references to use the pivot table you created in the steps above.

Then, when you updated the spreadsheet data, the formulas will update and not be lost or broken. If you have SharePoint where you are, you can upload the spreadsheet into a document list, and set it to update on a schedule.